react-text-mask the cursor behaves incorrectly
Я использую react-text-mask и Input antd.
I have a problem. When I want to use a phone number mask, when I delete a character from the middle of the line, my cursor moves to the beginning of the line. I solved this problem by saving the cursor position. But in the end the mask input doesn't work for me. I want to enter the phone number 1234567890, I enter it from the keyboard. I get (234) 789-0651, because the position of the cursor does not ignore ( and space.
how to fix this? the solution should work for any input mask.


export const MaskedInput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState();
  const mask = [
    "(",
    /[1-9]/,
    /[0-9]/,
    /[0-9]/,
    ")",
    " ",
    /[0-9]/,
    /[0-9]/,
    /[0-9]/,
    "-",
    /[0-9]/,
    /[0-9]/,
    /[0-9]/,
    /[0-9]/,
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current?.setSelectionRange(cursor, cursor);
  }, [cursor]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const { conformedValue } = conformToMask(value, mask, {
      guide: true,
      keepCharPositions: true, // Set to true to maintain character positions
    });
    setInputValue(conformedValue);
    setCursor(event.target.selectionStart);
  };

  return (
    <Input
      ref={(node) => {
        inputRef.current = node?.input; // Сохраняем реф на элемент input
        if (typeof ref === "function") {
          ref(node);
        }
      }}
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder="(123) 456-7890"
    />
  );
};



codesandbox
